# Differential equation of circle.

Tags: derivatives

Form differential equation of circle having centre on y axis and radius is 3 units
I got the answer but its not matching.
I got $x+y\frac{dy}{dx}-3\frac{dy}{dx} =0$.
Please suggest is that correct.

Comment: First of all, this does not look like an equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^{2}+(y-b)^{2}=9$$
By differentiating.
$$2x+2(y-b)(y')=0$$
Now make value of (y-b) and put it in equation of circle
$$(y-b) = \frac{-x}{y'}$$
And you will get 
$$(x^{2}-9)(y'^{2})+x^{2}=0$$

Comment: Thanks you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(0,c)$ be the center of the circle and $r = 3, c > 0 \Rightarrow x^2+(y-c)^2 = 3^2=9\Rightarrow 2x+2(y-c)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0\Rightarrow x + (y-c)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$

Comment: Just a doubt. Wouldn't you have to differentiate it once again and eliminate c in order to get a D.E. without c ?

Comment: You shouldn't eliminate $c$ since it is a constant. If you want to eliminate then you eliminate a variable $x$ or $y$.

Comment: your answer is just as i have done as the centre is on y axis and raius is 3 c=3 . and thats not matching.

Comment: c is a parameter here ... not really a constant... more like a variable constant. Anyways, I might post it and see what others think. Thanks

Comment: I think shailesh is right as its not given that the circle passes through origin.

Comment: A1DHTH is correct. You are confusing $c$ with the value of the radius. $c$ is not the radius, it is an arbitrary coordinate for the center's y-value.

Answer (score 1):

Slope of normal line between  $(0,3) - (x,y) =\dfrac{y-3}{x} $

So, slope of tangent  line $\dfrac {dy}{dx} @( x,y ) $  is its negative reciprocal $ \dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-x}{y-3} $

Simplifying, it correctly comes to what you have given.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a parametric equation, $$\dot{x} = y$$ $$\dot{y}=-x$$
with $x(0) = x_0$ and $y(0) = y_0$ is also a circle centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$. You can change the center by simply translating $x$ and $y$.